# Executing a python script through php button

Tags: php, python

I am having an issue with executing my python script through using a button on PHP. I looked through any or all relevant questions regarding my issue, and tried any answers i could find and modifying the file name to my own.
This is the PHP code on my website:

```
    <FORM>
    <button type="button" onclick="parent.location='action.php'">open</button>
    </FORM>
```

The PHP code will be executing the python script, which i wrote:

```
    <?
       exec("python /var/www/open.py")
    ?>
```

The website works, the python script works when i manually execute it on terminal. However, when i try to click on the button on my website, nothing happens. I also went and changed the configs on the sudoers file so that www-data functions without the use of a password, and also did chmod gu+x on /var/www/open.py.

Is there anything else that I might be missing? Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Which logs would you be talking about?

Comment: try echo exec("python /var/www/open.py");

Comment: alternatively you could use `system` instead of `exec` to avoid need for `echo` as seen in comment above

Comment: I gave your suggestion a shot. The line system("python /var/www/open.py"); doesn't seem to function. Could there be an issue with how I have written 
`<button type="button" onclick="parent.location='action.php'">open</button>`

please let me know

Comment: You have two separate problems.  1. Do you actually perform the exec statement? 2. Does exec work?  Add php trace message for (1).  Change exec to do `date` to ensure exec is working.  Then, try "exec /usr/bin/python /var/www/hello_world.py".  As others said, try selinux in permissive mode.  I bet it does _not_ like /usr/bin/python from web server.  You may need to create a custom exception rule.  Check /var/log/audit/audit.log and /var/log/secure and system log messages, and web server logs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming.

Answer (score 2):

It could just be a PATH problem since the user www-data doesn't have a path set. Try using:

```
<?
   exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/open.py")
?>
```

and see if that makes a difference (check that `/usr/bin/python` is the correct path for your distribution first with `which python`).

Answer (score 0):

Could 2 paths to resolution:

1. fetch http://my.site.com/action.php directly and confirm that code execures that way. In case of some PHP issues.
2. SELinux: if your SELinux is set to "enforcing", try temporary disabling it just to confirm that it's not in the way: "setenforcing Permissive". If that cures the issue - you know you need to adjust things. First and foremost I doubt any default policy would allow executable scripts in /var/www dir, check your distro's default policy and locate appropriate folder. /var/www/cgi-bin may be one of them, or possibly system-wide directory like /usr/local/bin etc.

Answer (score -1):

there are builtin php methods for this job : shell_exec() or system()